# In CentOS7, can not start MySQL

Tags: mysql, centos

I want use MySQL on CentOS7.
installed MySQL package using yum.

```
[root@node01 ~]# yum install mysql mysql-*
```

then,

```
[root@node01 ~]# systemctl start mysqld.service
Failed to issue method call: Unit mysqld.service failed to load: No such file or directory.
```

i can not execute MySQL. How can i solve this problem?

Comment: I think you have to use MariaDB instead of MySql.

Answer (score 25):

when you run

```
yum install mysql
```

command by default it installs `mariadb` not `mysql`. so try this following command

```
yum list installed | grep mariadb
```

if mariadb-server is missing try this following command

```
yum install mariadb-server
```

it installs the server package then start the service

```
systemctl start mariadb
```

or

```
service mariadb start
```

My issue is solved in this way.
Thanks

Comment: if coming from an earlier version of MariaDB to MariaDB 10.4.x this answer here is a life saver.

Comment: I had tried so many things but none command works, This works well.

Answer (score 15):

To check for the required packages, type the given command:

```
$ rpm -qa | grep mariadb
```

**Output**:

```
    mariadb-libs-5.5.44-2.el7.centos.x86_64
    mariadb-5.5.44-2.el7.centos.x86_64
    mariadb-devel-5.5.44-2.el7.centos.x86_64
    mariadb-server-5.5.44-2.el7.centos.x86_64
```

If the last package is absent, type the given commands:

```
$ sudo yum -y install mariadb-server

$ sudo systemctl start mariadb

$ cat /etc/redhat-release
```

**Output**:

```
CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)
```

Comment: I also have same configuration, but none of the mentioned method is working. I am getting this error in installing mariadb-server from above command, `Package 1:mariadb-server-5.5.50-1.el7_2.x86_64 is obsoleted by mysql-community-server-5.7.16-1.el7.x86_64 which is already installed
Nothing to do`. What can I do??

Comment: I can add that in my case, mariadb-devel-5.5.44-2.el7.centos.x86_64 was not present, so I $ yum install -y mariadb-dev and it was able to start.

Comment: Followed your instruction, mariadb.service was removed from my cluster.

Answer (score 7):

Check /etc/init.d/ for your mysql service name and then

service mysql_service_name start

On centos it is either:
**service mysqld start**
or for MariaDB:
**service mariadb start**

Comment: This function worked after logging in from super admin. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

mysql-community-common appears to be installed along with Red Hat-based *nix v7 installs and it in turn conflicts with mariadb installation. I'm using Oracle Linux 7, just ran into this. After a fresh install of OL7, mysql-community-common and mysql-community-libs are installed. Remove mysql-community-common THEN install mariadb and everything works like a champ.

```
root@ol7-101:~> yum list installed | grep mysql
mysql-community-common.x86_64       5.6.27-2.el7                   @Server-Mysql/7.2
mysql-community-libs.x86_64         5.6.27-2.el7                   @Server-Mysql/7.2
root@ol7-101:~>

root@ol7-101:~> yum install mariadb-server mariadb -y
Loaded plugins: ulninfo
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check    
[...]

86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-community-common-5.6.27-2.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/spanish/errmsg.sys from install of MariaDB-server-10.1.11-1.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-community-common-5.6.27-2.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/swedish/errmsg.sys from install of MariaDB-server-10.1.11-1.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-community-common-5.6.27-2.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/ukrainian/errmsg.sys from install of MariaDB-server-10.1.11-1.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-community-common-5.6.27-2.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/errmsg-utf8.txt from install of MariaDB-server-10.1.11-1.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-community-common-5.6.27-2.el7.x86_64

Error Summary
-------------

root@ol7-101:~> systemctl start mariadb
Failed to start mariadb.service: Unit mariadb.service failed to load: No such file or directory.

root@ol7-101:~> systemctl enable mariadb.service
Failed to execute operation: Access denied
root@ol7-101:~>

root@ol7-101:~> yum erase mysql-community-common.x86_64
Loaded plugins: ulninfo
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql-community-common.x86_64 0:5.6.27-2.el7 will be erased
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
[...]    

root@ol7-101:~> yum install mariadb  mariadb-libs mariadb-server -y
Loaded plugins: ulninfo
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check    
[...]

Complete!

root@ol7-101:~> systemctl start mariadb.service
root@ol7-101:~>
root@ol7-101:~> systemctl enable mariadb.service
Created symlink from /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/mariadb.service to /usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service.
root@ol7-101:~>
```

Answer (score 1):

CentOS7 use mariaDB replaced Mysql, you can use mariaDB as same as Mysql. Or you can download repo from [mysql.com](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/yum/). And then you can install mysql

Answer (score 0):

I had this error today, problem in my case was that ... **mysql actually failed to install**, but I didn't notice the error. If you run `which mysql` and it returns no mysql path, that is probablty the case. Or check the output when you tried to install MySQL:

```
yum install mysql-community-server.x86_64

[...]

Public key for mysql-community-server-5.7.44-1.el7.x86_64.rpm is not installed

 Failing package is: mysql-community-server-5.7.44-1.el7.x86_64
 GPG Keys are configured as: file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql
```

And was fixed by importing keys from mysql website:

```
rpm --import https://repo.mysql.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql
rpm --import https://repo.mysql.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql-2022
```

Then started the install again with yum:

```
yum install mysql-community-server.x86_64
```