# Start mysql in CentOS7, Failed to start mysql.service: Unit not found

Tags: mysql, hive, centos7

when I type the command:

`systemctl start mysql` in `CentOS7`, I get the following message:

```
Failed to start mysql.service: Unit not found
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: same error, did you got solution

Answer (score 4):

Use the command `service mysqld start`.

it can work in centos7 for mysql8.0

Answer (score 2):

Use this thread. It Worked for me. I was facing the same error after

```
yum install mysql
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34654662/7773802

Answer (score 1):

I fix this issue using

```
1. I uninstalled the mariadb maridb-server packages
2. I removed the directory /var/lib/mysql. ( mv /var/lib/mysql /mysqlbak)
3 Reinstalled the Mariadb, Mariadb-server packages.
4. systemct start mariadb; systemctl enable mariadb (problem solved).
```