# I have a problem with MySQL on Putty I am using Centos 7

Tags: centos7, putty

[ERROR image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwQAR.png)

I have tried everything to get mysql working but nothing works and I am on centos 7, I installed my sql but it just didn't work and I have tried to uninstall and put it back but it just wont work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't want to seem like I'm avoiding an answer but I believe this question is an exact duplicate of this: In CentOS7, can not start MySQL - [In CentOS7, can not start MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31067135/in-centos7-can-not-start-mysql)

The answer to your problem is there. i.e.

```
yum install mysql
```

installs mariadb not mysql, by default.

If you use

```
yum list installed | grep mariadb
```

and it's not there, then

```
yum install mariadb-server
```

will install it then start it.

Alternatively, use these commands to start it

```
systemctl start mariadb
```

or

```
service mariadb start
```

There should have been a clue to you when you ran the "start mysql" and got an error message that there was no mysql.